# Dash:graph_update with multiple drop down selection condition

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

Hello I am very new to dash and I am trying to render a graph whose outpuut would depend on the two drop down selection on the layput
I have written the below graph_update logic, however somehow it is not workig.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.H1('Stock Tickers'),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='my-dropdown',
            options=[
                {'label': 'A', 'value': 'A'},
                {'label': 'B', 'value': 'B'},
                {'label': 'C', 'value': 'C'}
            ],
            value='A'
        )
    ],
        style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block'}
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown1',
        options=[
            {'label': '250,000', 'value': '250000'},
            {'label': '500,000', 'value': '500000'},
            {'label': '750,000', 'value': '750000'},
            {'label': '1,000,000', 'value': '1000000'}
        ],
        value='250000'
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='my-graph')
], className="container")

@app.callback(Output('my-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('my-dropdown', 'value'), Input('my-dropdown1', 'value')])

 def update_graph(selected_dropdown_value, selected_imp_value):
     dff = df[(df['Demo'] == selected_dropdown_value) & (df['Imp_cap'] == selected_impresession_value)]
     return {
         'data': [{
             'x': dff.Imp
             'y': dff.user,
             'line': {
                 'width': 3,
                 'shape': 'spline'
             }
         }],
         'layout': {
             'margin': {
                 'l': 30,
                 'r': 20,
                 'b': 30,
                 't': 20
             }
         }
     }
```

I was hoping if someone can please help me to resolve the issue

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: This is very difficult to do without an example dataframe to work with. However, you have several syntax errors you can correct to start off. You need a comma after `'x': dff.Imp`, and you need to change `selected_impresession_value` to `selected_imp_value`, because that's how you defined the parameter for the function. If you can edit your post to include an example `df`, I'll try to help more!

Comment: Hello coralvanda, Thanks for your response. really appreciate it. I was managed to do it. I am not sure if it is the best way to do it. Any thoughts ??

Answer (score 1):

This is how we managed to do it. It was not something exceptionally genius, just the way of writing it.

```
def update_graph(n_clicks, input1, input2, input3, input4):
    dff = df[df['Demo'] == input1]
    df1 = dff[dff['Month'] == input2]
    df2 = df1[df1['Imp'] == input3]
    df3 = df2[df2['imp_cap'] == input4]
    if n_clicks < 1:
        return []
    else:
        return {
            'data': [{
                'x': df3.Variable2,
                'y': df3.Variable1,
                'line': {
                    'width': 3,
                    'shape': 'spline'
                }
            }],
            'layout': dict(
                # 'margin': {
                #     'l': 30,
                #     'r': 20,
                #     'b': 30,
                #     't': 50
                # },
                title='title',
                xaxis=dict(title='x-title'),
                yaxis=dict(title='y-title'),
                annotations=[make_annotation_item(x=df3['Variable1'].iloc[-1], y=df3['Variable2'].iloc[-1])]
            )
        }
```